# How to pass a parameter with *slashes* in the url?

Tags: python, flask

What I want to do is to pass the dates inside the parameter of a function, then process the input. Here's the function for it

```
@HR.route('/confirm_sickLeave/<date>/<user>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirm_sickLeave(user,date):
    u = User.query.filter_by(username=user.username).first()
    print u
    us = UserStatistics.filter_by(userId=u.id).first()
    temp = us.slDates
    dates = temp.keys()
    for a in dates:
        if a == date:
            temp['date'] = True
            flash('Date Confirmed.')
            return redirect(url_for('.approval_of_leaves'))


    return redirect(url_for('.approval_of_leaves'))
```

Now, my problem was I can't pass the values in my function. The reason was my input `dates` had slashes (`/`) in it. Let me show you:

**HTML:**

```
{% for u in all_users %}
## Returns all the dates applied by the user (it's in dict format)
{% set user_info = u.return_sickLeaves(u.username) %}  
{% for us in user_info %}
<tr>

        <td>     {{ u.username }}   </td>
        <td>     {{ us|e }} </td>
        {% if us.value|e == True %}
        <td class="success">Confirmed</td>
        {% else %}
        <td class="warning">Pending..</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td><a href = "{{ url_for('HR.confirm_sickLeave', user=u.username, date= us|e) }}">Confirm</a>
            <a href = "#">Deny</a>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, when I try to click confirm button, the response that I get is `Error 404 not found`. The url of the 404 error is: http://localhost:5000/confirm_sickLeave/02/01/2015%3B02/02/2015/seer

Is there any alternatives I can do? Thank you for you contribution. :)

Comment: Format the date for the url so it's `2015-02-02`.

Comment: Not Sure how it works in python , but if you need to read values you can encode the / to %09 and then send . see url Encoding

Answer (score 7):

Slashes carry meaning in a URL path, so the default converter for a path section explicitly *excludes* slashes.

You have two options:

- Explicitly match the separate parts of the date and re-constitute:

  ```
  @HR.route('/confirm_sickLeave/<year>/<month>/<day>/<user>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def confirm_sickLeave(user, year, month, day):
      date = '/'.join([year, month, day])
  ```
- Format your dates to use a different separator, like a `-`.

You *can* match slashes in paths, with the `path` converter (so `/confirm_sickLeave/<path:date>/<user>`), but that means you now match an *arbitrary number of slashes* in the path, making validation harder.

Comment: Hey @Martijn Pieters , for example how about a user having value as 'test me' ? and how to ignore replace it with a hyphen just in for the URL?

Comment: @Codenewbie Just URL encode the value; spaces become `%20`, Flask handles that transparently.

Comment: How can I replace %20 to a hyphen instead mate ? for e.g.: app.route('/<variable>/') and variable has value 'new base' , how to show in URL like 'new-base' instead of 'new%20base' ?

Comment: @Codenewbie Don’t. Because you can’t then remove the dash again to get a space and still keep *original* dashes, if you have two users called `test super user` and `test super-user` you’d get `test-super-user` in both cases and *you can’t reverse the process*. Also don’t call people “mate”, please. I’m a volunteer, like everyone else here, not service personnel to get impatient with.

Comment: @Codenewbie if you don’t care about reversal, just use manual string replacement (e.g. in Python: `username.replace(' ', '-')`). If you don’t care about how people react to using *mate* in a sentence like that, I’ll point you to our [help/behavior] and the fact that this has strayed way into [secondary discussion territory](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). You *should really* be using [chat] for inquiries like these.